# getting error importing spacy in my jupiter notebook

Tags: spacy

i have pip installed spacy it's already there, but when I import it I get error

Here is a screenshot for details

[image: 1]

Comment: Could you include the full error message? (better as text than as a picture)
Thanks!

Comment: i have uploaded a screenshot

Comment: Don't use screenshots of code or errors, paste them as text.